# How to call function in mail which is configured using Rules in drupal

Tags: rules, emails, tokens

I want to call function in mail body. I am using Rules modules for sending mail on some event triggers.

anyone have idea, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the mail content using [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7)

> hook_mail_alter() allows modification of email messages created and
>   sent with drupal_mail(). Usage examples include adding and/or changing
>   message text, message fields, and message headers.